# writing test using react-testing-library and react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm stuck for hours trying to test a simple page, I'm using **"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"**

I have this component that I want to test:

```
const Main: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<div>Home</div>}></Route>
        <Route
          path={"about"}
          element={<div>About</div>}
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Main
```

It worked well, then I have Main.test.tsx

```
const renderWithRouter = (ui: React.ReactElement, { route = '/' } = {}) => {
  window.history.pushState({}, 'Test page', route)

  return {
    user,
    ...render(ui, { wrapper: BrowserRouter }),
  }
}

describe('Main', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    renderWithRouter(<Main />, { route: '/about' })
  })

  test('should land on about page', async () => {
    await screen.findByText('about')
  })
})
```

but I got this error

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.]
```

Any clue why?

Comment: Because `renderWithRouter` is wrapping a component that already contains a `BrowserRouter` with _another `BrowserRouter`_. I generally move the router up to the `index.tsx` file, precisely so it's easy to test every other component that relies on router context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by using the `BrowserRouter` twice (you both wrapped the `Main` component and also its content). I would suggest you to **remove** the `BrowserRouter` from inside the `Main` component and instead wrap the root element with it. If the Main component is the root element the result will be this in the `index.tsx` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Main />
 </BrowserRouter>,
 document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Once you did that and removed the `BrowserRouter` from the `Main` component you will be good to go and you won't receive that error during the test.

More docs here: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/

Comment: tq so much! it's much more simpler than I thought!